# Website stuck in redirect loop for returning users even after issue resolution

Tags: php, redirect

Due a faulty update on a Drupal website, we had our website enter into infinite redirect loop in production. The update was removed in sometime and it started working for new visitors and who did not visit during the redirect loop issue.

But for the users who visited during that period, the website still shows same error even after it is resolved. Have tried empty cache and hard reload. What is causing the browser to be stuck in infinite redirect loop even after it is resolved? What can i do to resolve this for users?
[image]

Comment: Which header (30X status code) was used for the redirect?

Comment: We are in process of finding the root cause as it was due to addition of a big module and do not know what caused the redirect loop.